# UNMutableNotificationContent with custom object in userInfo crashes app

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to implement UNUserNotification in my app. In general it works, but I needed to pass my object with userInfo (and later receive it):

```
static func showNotification(_ serverNotification: ServerNotification){
    print("showNotification called")
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = serverNotification.title
    content.body = serverNotification.notificationDescription
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
    content.categoryIdentifier = "pl.tropicalapps.TryOnNotification"
    content.userInfo = ["serverNotification" : serverNotification]
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "Request", content: content, trigger: trigger)
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.add(request) { (error:Error?) in
        if let err = error {
            print(err)
        }
        else{
            print("notification sent!")
        }
    }
}
```

If I won't add userInfo or pass ["foo": "bar"] it works. But when I add my object (serverNotification) it crashes after sending the request. I can't catch this error, but it's in`-[NSXPCEncoder _checkObject:]: (rest is in assembler).

Here's ServerNotification class:

```
class ServerNotification : NSCoder {

    var id:Int
    var type:String
    var brandId:Int
    var title:String
    var notificationDescription:String = ""
    var discountId:String
    var discountPercent:Double
    var discountDescription:String
    var discountCode:String
    var discountType:String
    var discountExpireDate:Date
    var date:Date

    override init(){
        id = 0
        type = ""
        brandId = 0
        title = ""
        notificationDescription = ""
        discountId = ""
        discountPercent = 0.0
        discountDescription = ""
        discountCode = ""
        discountType = ""
        discountExpireDate = Date()
        date = Date()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        id = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "id")
        type = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "type") as! String
        brandId = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "brandId")
        title = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "title") as! String
        notificationDescription = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "notificationDescription") as! String
        discountId = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "discountId") as! String
        discountPercent = aDecoder.decodeDouble(forKey: "discountPercent")
        discountDescription = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "discountDescription")  as! String
        discountCode = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "discountCode")  as! String
        discountType = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "discountType") as! String
        discountExpireDate = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "discountExpireDate") as! Date
        date = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "date") as! Date
        super.init()
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(_ aCoder: NSCoder){
        aCoder.encode(id, forKey: "id")
        aCoder.encode(type, forKey: "type")
        aCoder.encode(brandId, forKey: "brandId")
        aCoder.encode(title, forKey: "title")
        aCoder.encode(notificationDescription, forKey: "notificationDescription")
        aCoder.encode(discountId, forKey: "discountId")
        aCoder.encode(discountPercent, forKey: "discountPercent")
        aCoder.encode(discountDescription, forKey: "discountDescription")
        aCoder.encode(discountCode, forKey: "discountCode")
        aCoder.encode(discountType, forKey: "discountType")
        aCoder.encode(discountExpireDate, forKey: "discountExpireDate")
        aCoder.encode(date, forKey: "date")
    }
}
```

Where's the problem? How can I fix this?
I'm running app on the device with iOS 10.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I tested your code with simulator, a little more followed **`-[NSXPCEncoder _checkObject:]:`**

> **`This coder only encodes objects that adopt NSSecureCoding (object is of class 'TestProjectName.ServerNotification').`**

You may need to make the header of your `ServerNotification` as:

```
class ServerNotification : NSObject, NSSecureCoding {
```

Xcode will show some suggestions with right "Fix-it"s.

You usually subclass `NSCoder` when you want to create your own archiver/unarchiver, other than that, such subclassing is useless.

Comment: Well, I use my own archiver/unarchiver.

Comment: @Makalele, archiver/unarchiver should be different from archived object. The class of archived objects needs to conform to `NSCoding` (**not** `NSCoder`) or `NSSecureCoding`, archiver/unarchiver inherits `NSCoder`. Do you really want to create a replacement for `NSKeyedArchiver`/`NSKeyedUnarchiver`?